# Swift Compiler Error Xcode 8

Tags: swift, xcode8

Getting the following error when trying to build my project in Xcode 8, any ideas?
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please add the log that comes out of Xcode when you compile your project so that we can see the extended error output.

Comment: This is reasonably common due to bugs in Xcode.  Quit Xcode, delete everything in your Derived Data folder (`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`), reopen your project and build again.  Usually that clears it up.

Comment: #par, you should put this into the answer